# best way to compare differences between lists

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have two sets of lists below:

List 1 Info
ID = 1
PersonFirstName = Sarah
PersonLastName = Smith
PersonFavoriteFood = Pizza
PersonFavoriteColor = Purple
PersonFavoriteFlower = Lily

List 2 Info
ID = 1
PersonFirstName = Sarah
PersonLastName = Smith
PersonFavoriteFood = Hamburger
PersonFavoriteColor = Yellow
PersonFavoriteFlower = Rose

As you can see - Sarah Smith came into some system and changed her favorite food, favorite color and favorite flower. If her manager were to come into this app and open it up he would see three rows in the history of Sarah Smith's record:

Date Changed = 2/16
Field Changed = PersonFavoriteFood
Original Value = Pizza
Changed Value = Hamburger
Changed By = Sarah Smith

Date Changed = 2/16
Field Changed = PersonFavoriteColor
Original Value = Purple
Changed Value = Yellow
Changed By = Sarah Smith

Date Changed = 2/16
Field Changed = PersonFavoriteFlower
Original Value = Lily
Changed Value = Rose
Changed By = Sarah Smith

The threee rows he sees need to be saved in the database in that way. So thats one table with two rows (original row and changed row) and another table with as many rows as there were changes and what those changes were (food, color, flower). I can easily get the first table with the original and changed row. I am suck in my VB.NET code going through LINQ on these two lists (the original and changed). My thought is to select value from each column in each list, determine if it is different, if it is then save it to other table, if it isn't then get the next column from each list and compare. But is there an easier way?

My link code is:

```
Dim columnvalue1 = from a in OriginalList select a.column1
Dim columnvalue2 = from b in ChangedList select a.column1

If columnvalue1 = columnvalue2 then
SaveDifferencesToTable(colomnvalue1, columnvalue2)
End If
```

If there is a better way even if it is outside of LINQ please let me know. I can do it this way but I worry that it is the wrong way to do it.  I am using entity framework as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerable.Except method to create a set of differences. You can also implement your own comparer if you have to. In anyway, I am sure you will have to write some code.

Here is more details on the method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx